# Using Gulp and Browserify to bundle multiple files

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I am relatively new to front-end development, and have a question about using Gulp and Browserify together.

Here is a description of my setup: I have a project folder that contains everything related to my project (css, html, js, etc.) In my javascript directory, I have a sub-directory named "modules" which contains, say, three sub-directories of its own: A, B, and C.  Each of these three sub-directories contains any number of js files.  Take sub-directory A, for example; it may contain js files 1.js, 2.js, and 3.js.  Each of these may import (using the 'require' statement that Browserify recognizes) node dependencies.

I want Browserify/Gulp to give me a bundled js file for each of the sub-directories A, B, and C which contain the respective javascript files bundled along with their dependencies.  Take again the example js files above in the directory A: the build process should produce an output A.js that contains 1.js, 2.js, and 3.js, as well as the modules imported via 'require'.  Similar outputs should exist for B and C.

Thanks in advance for any pointers whatsoever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generating a file per folder](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md) recipe may guide you on how to execute a gulp flow per folder.

Comment: While a link can be useful, an answer should contain the answer in it, not just a link.